# Using SHA256 method of OpenSSL library in C#

Tags: c#, openssl, wrapper, sha, sha256

I'm coding a wrapper for OpenSSL for C#, and actually everything is working for me now, but i'm having a problem with one method. (I know about OpenSSL.Net, it just doesn't work as I need it and it is missing a lot of methods).

OpenSSL 1.0.1 has SHA256 that I'd like to use. The method itself in the OpenSSL lib C code:

```
unsigned char *SHA256(const unsigned char *d, size_t n, unsigned char *md)
{
    SHA256_CTX c;
    static unsigned char m[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    if (md == NULL)
        md = m;
    SHA256_Init(&c);
    SHA256_Update(&c, d, n);
    SHA256_Final(md, &c);
    OPENSSL_cleanse(&c, sizeof(c));
    return (md);
}
```

The function itself returns a pointer, and as parameters it needs the input data, the length of the data to hash, and an object for the hash.

I'm wrapping it in the next way:

```
[DllImport(DLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static IntPtr SHA256(byte[] data, long len, ref byte[] result);
```

I'm trying to run it the next way:

```
byte[] d = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
byte[] r = new byte[32];
IntPtr x = NOpenSSL.Wrapper.SHA256(d, d.Length, ref r);
Console.WriteLine(d.Length + " " + x + " " + r.Length + " " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(r));
```

And what i get for result: ***`16 1838788744 1`***. The `d.Length` is 16 OK, I get the x as a pointer OK, the `r.Length` becomes 1 byte that is impossible.

If I don't `ref` the `byte[]` in the method just simply give it to it nothing changes in the variable `r`.

Can anyone help me please what am i doing wrong?

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: .NET Core 5 wraps over OpenSSL for non Windows platforms and is so far that most complete wrapper I can think of with full unit test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some dicovery of the OpenSSL C source and experimenting with C# pointers and Marshaling it turned out the `SHA256` method does not put the result hash in the variable `md`, but it returns a pointer to the hash. (First i thought it's the pointer of the SHA256-struct, but it is the actual hash.)

The working C# code is the following:

```
[DllImport(DLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static IntPtr SHA256(byte[] data, long len, byte[] result);
```

-

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("some_data_to_hash");

IntPtr r = NOpenSSL.Wrapper.SHA256(data, data.Length, null);
byte[] output = new byte[32];
Marshal.Copy(r, output, 0, output.Length);

// output contains now the 32 bytes of the hashed data
```

Since we are not using the 3rd variable of the `SHA256` method (we just pass `null` instead) the `ref` is needed to be removed from the `DllImport`.

*(Note: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/sha.html says: If md is NULL, the digest is placed in a static array. Note: setting md to NULL is not thread safe.)*

Using `SHA512` is exactly the same just we need to replace the method name at both places in the code and change the `output` byte[] `length` from `32` to `64`.